# Edit catalog layout

Tags: magento-2.1, layout

I understand that to edit the structure of some pages like category pages the file is `catalog_category_view.xml`, but I can't find any reference to breadcrumbs, titles in this file.

How can I edit those elements?

Answer (score 0):

As Magento 2 consists of a lot of modules, blocks and containers are created in modules and then imported in other modules. See [modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) for more info.

This means that the code you're looking for is often spread over multiple modules.

### Where the breadcrumbs are defined

The layout XML responsible for creating breadcrumbs is defined in the `Magento_Theme` module:

**File**: `magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` 
**Line**: 95

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

So you can still edit this in `catalog_category_view.xml`, for example if you wanted to remove the breadcrumbs on category pages only you would write:

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
```

---

Please add `catalog_category_view.xml` to your theme, never edit the core/vendor files!

Comment: Thanks for this. Yeah, i copied catalog_category_view.xml in my theme folder.

Comment: No problem, if it helps you out please mark the answer as accepted (green tick to the left).